# Is there an R function to replace values in one dataframe with values from another ONLY when values from another common variable are equal?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I have two dfs. I want to transfer the values from a column in one df into a column in the other df ONLY when the values from another column match cross both dfs.

The first df looks like this:

```r
A = data.frame(name = c('Ann', 'Charlie', 'James', 'Mary'),
count = c(0,0,0,0))
```

The second df looks like this:

```r
B = data.frame(name = c('Charlie', 'Mary'), count = (4, 11))
```

What I want is to change the count values from df A to the count values from df B where the names in df B match those in A:

New df A:

```r
name      count 
Anne        0
Charlie     4
James       0
Mary        11
```

Is there a way to use dplyr for this?

Comment: Use `match` ? `A$count <- B$count[match(A$name, B$name)]` Or `merge` ? `merge(A, B, by = "name", all.x = TRUE)[-2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can accomplish this:

```
> dplyr::left_join(A, B, "name") %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      transmute(name, count = sum(count.x, count.y, na.rm = TRUE))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  name    count
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Anne        0
2 Charlie     4
3 James       0
4 Mary       11
```

Or,

```
> left_join(A, B, "name") %>%
      transmute(name, count = rowSums(select(., starts_with("count")), na.rm = TRUE))
     name count
1    Anne     0
2 Charlie     4
3   James     0
4    Mary    11
```

**Caveat:** I read somewhere (I don't recall where) that the second approach is not supported by design, but it does give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

`A %>%`
`rename(count_A = count) %>%`
`left_join(B %>% rename(count_B = count), by = 'name') %>%`
`mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count_B), count_A, count_B))`

Comment: I think this is only answer that replaces the values rather than relying on sum with 0.

Answer (score 1):

The [dplyr joins](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) along with the [coalesce](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/coalesce) function should do the trick:

```
library(dyplr)

A %>% 
  left_join(B, by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(count = coalesce(count.y, count.x)) %>% 
  select(-count.x, -count.y)
```